# Consertando Celular x Desktop

Tags: html, css, background

Galera, boa noite.
Estou desde cedo tentando configurar o meu site.
Ele está funcionando perfeitamente na versão desktop e na versão celular ele cria uma parte em branco.
Eu já tentei de TUDO para resolver e não consigo.

[image: VERSÃO DESKTOP]
[image: VERSÃO MOBILE]

```css
html, body {
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 auto;
}

#background {
background: url (img/main) no-repeat;
height:650px;
background: url(img/main.jpg) no-repeat;
background-color:#efc500;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}

#bar {
height:130px;
background-color:white;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80%);
}

img.logotopo {float:left; margin-left:10px;}

#menu ul {
margin:0px auto;
margin-top:50px;
list-style:none;
float: right;
margin-right:10px;
}

#menu ul li { display: inline; }

#menu ul li a {
font-size:18px;
color:#efc500;
font-weight:bold;
margin-left: 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {border-bottom:6px solid #efc500;}

h1.textomain {
font-size: 5.0em;
color:#efc500;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:50px;
}

#botao {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
width:350px;
height:70px;
display:block;
position:relative;
top:50px;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:30px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80%);
}

a.botao {
color:#efc500;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:18px;
font-size:1.3em;
text-decoration:none;
}

#botao:hover {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100%);
}

#mae {
width: 1050px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 auto;
}

img.linha {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:50px;
position:relative;
display:block;
}

img.linha2 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:48px;
position:relative;
display:block;
}

h2.textomiddle {
font-size:2.5em;
color:#000000;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:italic;
text-align:center;
}

#dif1 {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
display:block;
}

#dif2 {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float:left;
margin-left:65px;
}

#dif3 {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
}

h3.meio {text-align:center; font-weight:normal; font-size:1.5em;}
p.meio {text-align:justify; position:relative; bottom:20px;]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
<meta name="language" content="PT-BR">
<meta name="author" content="Douglas Mion">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,all">
<meta name="keywords" content="Arquitetura, projetos, obras, paisagismo, arquitetos, arquiteto">
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon/1x/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style" href="style2.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">


<title>CR6 ARQUITETURA</title>

</head>

<div id="background">
   <div id="bar">
      <img class="logotopo" src="img/cr6logo.png">

      <nav id="menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="trabalhos.html">NOSSOS TRABALHOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="quem.html">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contato.html">CONTATO</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <h1 class="textomain">SOLUÇÃO COMPLETA EM ARQUITETURA</h1>
   <div id="botao">
      <a class="botao"href="contato.html">FAÇA UM ORÇAMENTO</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="mae">
   <img class="linha1" src="img/line.png">
   <h2 class="textomiddle">"Empresa de arquitetura focada em atender as demandas de seu projeto com toda a excelência e qualidade"</h2>
   <img class="linha2" src="img/line.png">
   <div id="dif1">
      <center><img class="meio" src="img/garantia-icon.png"></center>
      <h3 class="meio">GARANTIA</h3>
      <p class="meio">Nossa empresa oferece garantia de 5 anos para sua obra ou projeto, garantindo total satisfação do cliente e comprometimento da CR6.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="dif2">
      <center><img class="meio" src="img/price-icon.png"></center>
      <h3 class="meio">CUSTO</h3>
      <p class="meio">Juntar a qualidade do nosso serviço com o baixo custo que oferecemos é com certeza a melhor opção para você economizar em sua obra/projeto.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="dif3">
      <center><img class="meio" src="img/equipe-icon.png"></center>
      <h3 class="meio">EQUIPE</h3>
      <p class="meio">Juntar a qualidade do nosso serviço com o baixo custo que oferecemos é com certeza a melhor opção para você economizar em sua obra/projeto.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Em qual aparelho você testou? vi aqui pelo emulador de chrome e funcionou certinho o layout

Comment: @fernandoandrade testei em mais de 3 celulares diferentes e a barra branca na direita continua. Este é o site: www.cr6arquitetura.com.br

Comment: Opa, no site fica realmente, tinha copia seu código, vou ver aqui então se posso te ajudar ...

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo! Estou a dois dias tentando resolver esse problema e estou me matando pra resolver haha

Comment: O problema é que você definiu para alguns elementos `width: 1050px;` e para o `#bgmain` não com isso, ele fica pegando o tamanho do device enquanto (`width: 100%`) enquanto os outros elementos estão com tamanho forçado. O melhor seria vc colocar `width: auto` para tela pequenas com um media query

Comment: @fernandoandrade não há nenhum bgmain aí.. mas eu acho que eu te entendi.. Sabe me dizer como eu faço isso com a media query? Não sei trabalhar com design responsivo.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo na resposta, `bgmain` é a primeira div após `<body>`

Comment: MIL PERDÕES, eu te dei o site errado, em qual eu não mais estou trabalhando. Estou trabalhando mais, o site que estou trabalhando é o: www.cr6arquitetura.com.br/teste.html

Comment: De qualquer forma eu não entendi em QUAL lugar eu tenho de colocar o width: auto.

Comment: Poderia verificar nesse novo site que lhe enviei? @fernandoandrade

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @DougasMion. Agora é só você ajustar os blocos de texto do meio e do rodapé.

Comment: @fernandoandrade muitissímo obrigado cara, vou testar aqui e já falo se deu certo. uma última coisa, esses comandos eu substituo pelos já existentes, correto?

Comment: pode adicionar no final do arquivo `style2.css` mesmo.

Comment: É só copiar e colar isso que você me mandou e colocar no final do arquivo?

Comment: Sim, adiciona no final do arquivo.

Comment: @fernandoandrade funcionu em partes amigão, agora a partezinha onde fica a "equipe" está indo pra baixo e deixando uma enorme parte branca na página.

Comment: Esses aí você vai ter de ajustar o tamanho, tenta colocar em `%` por exemplo, `width: 33.33%` como são 3 blocos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você definiu o `width` para alguns elementos da página e para os que estão com a "barra" não. E também as imagens que estão sendo mostradas no tamanho real. Basta fazer assim:

```
#paisapro, .linha1, .linha2, .linha3, .paisapro {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#mae {
    width: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    #mae  {
        width: 1050px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Completamente resolvido!! Muito obrigado!